# How to redirect http to https without trailling slash in apache?

Tags: apache, server, web-config, ubuntu-16.04, configserver

I want to redirect a url from `http` to `https` but if the url doesn't have traillin slash it won't be redirect. I tried many way as I'm noobie in Apache I haven't done it.
this is the config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.nl
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.nl
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http:127.0.0.1:3001/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    Redirect permanent / https://mydomain.nl
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ProxyPassMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) directive instead of ProxyPass. It allows using regular expression for matching urls. For example:

```
ProxyPass (^.*[^\/]?$) http://127.0.0.1:3001/
```

The url should match if it contains no characters or it contains characters and does not end with "/"